# Which dataGridView event should be used for changing the content of a textBox immediately after editing it?

Tags: c#

I have a gridview with 2 column, one is a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn named "choose" , the other is an ordinary DataGridViewTextBoxColumn named "ID"... I want to change the text of a textbox immediately when the checked of chechkbox column changed .... but i don't know which event should i use ....

```
     void SetTextBox()
     { 
         TextBox1.Text="";
         for (int i = 0; i < MyGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(MyGrid.Rows[i].Cells["choose"].Value) == true)
            {                    
                TextBox1.Text += MyGrid.Rows[i].Cells["ID"].Value.ToString()+",";                   
            }
     }

     private void !!!!which Event?!!!!(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          SetTextBox();
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually two events you need to deal with.  Here's an example adapted from the code I'm working on right now.

```
    private void dgvRMADetail_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvRMADetail.CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell))
        {
            dgvRMADetail.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        }
    }

    private void dgvRMADetail_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == useRowCheckboxColumn.Index)
        {
           // Logic for doing whatever when the checkbox is checked.
        }
    }
```

The first event tells it "Automatically commit this when it changes", the second event is "When the value is committed, do something".